# Grouping Quarterly Data And Calculating SUM in the SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table of sales data with the following columns:

saleID,
saleDate,
saleAmount,
numberOfItems,
itemsArray

What I'm trying to do is write a query that will list quarterly sales data since 2017 with each row returned representing a quarter. I have accomplished this with the following query:

```
SELECT
  DATEPART(YEAR, saleDate) [YEAR],
  DATEPART(QUARTER, saleDate) [QUARTER],
  COUNT(1) [Total Sales],
  FORMAT(SUM(saleAmount), 'C', 'en-us') [Total Sales Revenue]
FROM
  tbl_sales
WHERE
  saleDate > '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY
  DATEPART(YEAR, saleDate), DATEPART(QUARTER, saleDate)
ORDER BY
  1,2
```

This gives me a quarter per row in the results, which is great. What I'm struggling with is I want to also have a column in the results that shows a weighted average of the number of items per sale. The weighted average I want to calculate is:

```
SUM(saleAmount/[Total Sales Revenue]*numberOfItems)
```

Is there a way to do this all with one query? Any time I try to do this, I get an Invalid Column Name error:

```
SELECT
  DATEPART(YEAR, saleDate) [YEAR],
  DATEPART(QUARTER, saleDate) [QUARTER],
  COUNT(1) [Total Sales],
  FORMAT(SUM(saleAmount), 'C', 'en-us') [Total Sales Revenue],
  SUM(saleAmount/[Total Sales Revenue]*numberOfItems)
FROM
  tbl_sales
WHERE
  saleDate > '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY
  DATEPART(YEAR, saleDate), DATEPART(QUARTER, saleDate)
ORDER BY
  1,2

----
Invalid column name 'Total Sales Revenue'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can't use alias [Total Sales Revenue] in <code>SUM(saleAmount/[Total Sales Revenue]*numberOfItems)</code>.

Can You provide table definition ?

I guess You can achieve what You want using select from another subselect

Comment: I recommend against `FORMAT`, it has terrible performance issues. Formatting should be left to the presentation layer. Also, your expression for `[Total Sales Revenue]` returns a `varchar`. How to you divide a numerical value like `123456` by the string value `'$1,234.56'`? How many times does the string '$' go into a number?

Comment: Sampe data and expected result will really help here. Also note this: [Bad habits to kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal). you should really replace `ORDER BY 1,2` with `ORDER BY [YEAR], [QUARTER]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Need to calcualte the total first in the cte:

```
;WITH cte_sum (
SELECT
  DATEPART(YEAR, saleDate) [YEAR],
  DATEPART(QUARTER, saleDate) [QUARTER],
  SUM(saleAmount) AS TotalSales
FROM
  tbl_sales
WHERE
  saleDate > '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY
  DATEPART(YEAR, saleDate), DATEPART(QUARTER, saleDate)
)
SELECT t.[YEAR],t.[QUARTER],
  FORMAT(MAX(t.TotalSales), 'C', 'en-us') [Total Sales Revenue],
  SUM(s.saleAmount/t.TotalSales*s.numberOfItems) AS WeightedAvg
FROM tbl_sales s
INNER JOIN cte_sum t
ON DATEPART(YEAR, s.saleDate)=t.[YEAR]
AND DATEPART(QUARTER, s.saleDate)=t.[QUARTER]
GROUP BY t.[YEAR],t.[QUARTER]
```

Comment: Also need to add WHERE s.saleDate > '2017-01-01' for better performance

Comment: Thank you. This gives me exactly what I need. I'm rusty on my SQL and completely forgot about nesting with cte!